# How does the data packet flow work between S3 and cloudfront in AWS when S3 object is access/updated by multiple regions?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

S3 bucket on Region 1 and use cloud front service
1. from Region 2 user pull the file from the s3 bucket first time through the edge server make some changes and upload.
2. After that a user from Region 1 makes changes to the same file in bucket and upload the changes.
Now users from Region 2 again pull the file from s3 bucket, how does the data packet flow work ? does the edge work check with the main server (s3 bucket )at the time requested by Region 2 user or the cached file on the edge server is automatically updated?

Answer (score 0):

CF **does not check** whether your original S3 object has been updated or not. Cached objects stay in CF for as long as they are valid or CF deems them as not popular enough to keep them.

If you want to force CF do discard old files and start using new ones you have to [invalidating your files](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Invalidation.html) yourself, or use any of the recommended strategies for managing that, such as [using versioned file names](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/UpdatingExistingObjects.html#ReplacingObjects).